# SwiftData relationships

Tags: swift, synchronization, swift-data

Second attempt for this question, hopefully this one will be a little clearer than the first one.

I am designing an offline-first app that needs to download and keep a set of data locally on the device, update it, and sync it back to a web server.

My system has over 30 tables, and each table has several relationships with other ones. In my previous attempts, my syncing system identified records to be synced on each side (local and web service) for the tables being used and sent only the records that were required. The relationships were maintained using keys and were therefore automatically "created" when the records were fetched from the local database.

SwiftData brings another strategy to this as the framework manages the relationships between related objects "automatically". If we take this code as an example:

```
final class Student {
    let nameFirst: String
    let nameLast: String
    var school: School?
}

final class School {
    let name: String
    @Relationship(.inverse: \Student.school)
    var students: [Student]
}
```

In my previous design, my syncing system would take each of the table separately, find each record that needed an update and downloaded them. Data transfer was minimal, and it seemed to make sense from a database management point of view as the data persisted for each download was only exactly what had been modified (at a record level).

With SwiftData, it seems like I need to populate all of the related data as well as the piece of data that is in need of an update. If, for example, a student record needs to be downloaded again from the web service, I also need to download with it the school record to maintain the relationship, which means that I would download the same school record several times if I was going to download a list of all students in a school.

While it might now make a big difference with a small scale as shown above, my actual system has a lot more info and I can see the data usage going up dramatically if I need to download the record and its related records for each update.

I have made several tests and it looks like I can update the parent record without breaking the relationships. Using my example above, it looks like School can be upserted without losing the relationship.

I can't seem to update Student without redownloading the parent School record in entirety to upsert it. If I just omit it, it removes the foreign key in the SQLite database and I lose the association between the two.

I think it leaves me with two choices:

1. Download duplicate data to maintain data integrity, while attempting to minimize it.
2. Rebuild relationships on the device, either when required or after download.

Have I missed something?